# Create a button on Infopath for users to export form to PDF

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Currently I have created a travel request form using Sharepoint 2013 and Infopath 2013 that once you submit the form, it creates a line item on the list as well as workflows to their managers for approval.

Once the managers have approved the form, on the form itself there is a field called "Approver" and "Approved On" that shows who and when the form was approved.

I want the users to then be able to open the form and have a button to export AFTER the form has been approved, to PDF. Is this possible? I do not want it to be automatic.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I know I suggested you to post it here as well, but for completeness, see my original answer on StackOverflow. Perhaps it will be of use to someone else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266508/create-a-button-on-infopath-for-users-to-export-form-to-pdf/26274761?noredirect=1#comment41236734_26274761